# Alternative definition improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Suppose we have a function, $f$, that is Riemann-integrable on every closed subset of $]0,1]$. The improper Riemann integral of $f$ is defined as $\lim_{a\to 0^{+}} \int_a^{1} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$, if the limit exists.

Now for each positive $R$ define a new function $f_R$ such that $f_R(x)=f(x)$ if $-R<f(x)<R$, $f_R(x)=R$ if $f(x)\geq R$ and $f_R(x)=-R$ if $f(x)\leq -R.$

Can the improper integral also be defined as $\lim_{R\to \infty} \int_0^{1} f_R(x) \mathrm{d}x$?

If $f$ is a positive function the answer is yes, which can be proven using the Lebesgue integral. In general my guess the answer is no, but it would be interesting to have a counterexample, because it seems like an equally natural definition of the improper integral.

Comment: Well, for any $R>1$ $f_R\equiv f$ on $[0,1]$. So the limit only makes sense if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: This alternative definition you give doesn't seem to be useful, since the issue is at $x=0$ and your definition of $f_R$ is centered around zero, so for any positive $R$ it relies on an improper integral (circular). 

There are alternative definitions of improper integrals. Most useful ones are equivalent for most cases, but some interesting differences occur. See for example the Cauchy principle value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). This is one (minor) motivation for Lebesgue integration, which circumvents issues like this.

Comment: No, we don't need to rely on improper integrals in this definition. Each f_R is bounded and also continuous almost everywhere (since f must be continuous almost everywhere), so f_R will be Riemann-integrable.